# floating hearts animation with react native

Tags: react-native, animation

I'm trying to create floating hearts animation like below when user likes an item:

[image: floating hearts animation]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with [Lottie](https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native). Lottie is a mobile library that parses `Adobe After Effects` animations exported as JSON with `bodymovin` and renders them natively on mobile.

Available animations:

https://lottiefiles.com/featured

Heart Animations:

https://lottiefiles.com/search?q=hearts&category=animations

Similar animations as your need:

https://lottiefiles.com/8338-heart-like-button

Comment: thank you for your answer, but lottie have some limitations. for example we can not change the color, spacing,...

Comment: You are using someone else animations, create your own using `After Effects`. Later use it in `Lottie`.